# Force IDataErrorInfo validation

Tags: wpf, validation, idataerrorinfo

I have two controls on some panel: textbox and combobox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ShapeName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />

<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding ActiveStageViewModel, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

I need to force idataerrorinfo validation for textbox, when I select something on combobox. How to do that?

The code from viewmodel:

```
string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
      get
      {
        var error = string.Empty;

        if (propertyName == Expression.GetPropertyName(() => ActiveStageViewModel))
        {
          // TODO: Add functionality to force ShapeName property validation
          return error;
        }

        if (propertyName == Expression.GetPropertyName(() => ShapeName))
        {
          error = ValidateShapeName();
        }

        TooltipMessage = error;
        return error;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just raise the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event for the property you want to validate or if you are in .NET 4.5 or Silverlight 4 use the [INotityDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: yea...NotifyPropertyChanged works) I have tried before, but forgot about two way mode...

Comment: I've used  [AlsoNotifyFor("ShapeName")] over ActiveStageViewModel

Comment: It kinda works... In my case I have a `TabControl` and in the last tab when user clicks save for the first time, I raise `NotifyPropertyChanged` and the error is shown. However, when I go back to other tab, and switch back again to the last tab, raising `NotifyPropertyChanged` does not work, no error template is shown. Any insights?

Comment: @JobaDiniz You have a solution to this yet?

Comment: @JobaDiniz Ok I found a solution in case you need it [so link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907075/textbox-with-validation-loses-errortemplate-on-tab-change)

Answer (score 16):

Worth remembering also that you can raise NotifyPropertyChanged with String.Empty property.  This will force validation of all properties at that level.  Can be useful at times.