# ValidationTemplate not always show in TabControl

Tags: wpf, validation

first my validation template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTemplate" >
    <Grid>
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="MyAdornedElement" />
        <Path x:Name="path"  Margin="-2,-2,0,0" Data="M 0,10 L 10,0 L 0,0 Z" Fill="{StaticResource BrushError}" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="White" 
               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=MyAdornedElement,Path=AdornedElement.Visibility}"
               ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=MyAdornedElement,Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

and my textbox style

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ValidationTemplate}"/>
    <Setter Property="UndoLimit" Value="0"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource IsFocusBorderThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource IsFocusBorderBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource IsDisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and now the mysterius behavior

i have a tabcontrol with 2 tabpages, each of the pages contains textboxes. if i open my view and move from first to second tabpage a back and then push the validate button - all is fine, my validation template is shown for all textboxes on both tabpages.

BUT when i just open the view and dont navigate to tabpage 2 - then push the validate button - just the textboxes on tabpage 1 have the validation template shown. even more when i hit the button again on the validation template its not show on tabpage 2.

Any hints what i'm missing?

EDIT:
if i use snoop and walk on the snoop treeview to my textbox on tabpage 2, then the validation Template Adorner is visible as far as i click on the TextBox in the Snoop Treeview...

Comment: I think that question might explain what happenned to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907075/textbox-with-validation-loses-errortemplate-on-tab-change

Answer (score 1):

if i add the following to my textbox style it works.

```
 <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ValidationTemplate}"/>
 </Trigger>
```