# Error template get lost when changing tab in MahApps.Metro

Tags: mahapps.metro

In my window I have 2 tabs. One with the main informarion and the other one with an editable grid. When I click the save button the entire window gets validated and the controls with validation problems are highlighted in red. But if i change the tab to the one with the grid and get back to the one with the validation problems the controls are not highlighted anymore. Even if i click the save button again, and the validation happens, the controls never get highlighted again.

Here are the screen captures

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

it's a bit late, but today I had the same situation and found the solution.
You have to add a AdornerDecorator inside the TabItem:

```
<TabItem Header="Foo">
        <AdornerDecorator>
           //more content
        </AdornerDecorator>
</TabItem>
```

I have found it in a more general question:
[TextBox with validation loses ErrorTemplate on tab change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907075/textbox-with-validation-loses-errortemplate-on-tab-change)

Greetings