# How to make INotifyDataErrorInfo errors persistent until corrected?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, validationattribute, inotifydataerrorinfo

My validation works in the first instance but when I go from one Tab Item to another and back again the validation is gone.

I would have expected this state to be persistent until the user inputs the valid passing criteria in this scenario.

Maybe this is expected behaviour, and I have missed something in the documentation.

In my application I have a **MainWindow.xaml**, and a **MainWindowViewModel.cs** as its DataContext which inherits from a **BaseViewModel.cs** that implements **INotifyPropertyChanged**, and **INotifyDataErrorInfo**. Then I have created a custom **ValidationAttribute** called **FilePath.cs**.

The MainWindow.xaml consists of a Tab Control with two Tab Items. Only one has a text boxs which I have implemented my validation on. This works in the sense that it notifies me when the validation is incorrect. In this example the file path does not exist.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
  <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Boxs">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Column="0"
                       Grid.Row="0"
                       Content="File Path" />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1"
                         Grid.Row="0"
                         Margin="5,5,5,5"
                         Text="{Binding FilePath, 
                                        Mode=TwoWay, 
                                        NotifyOnValidationError=True, 
                                        ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True,
                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Blank"/>
    </TabControl>
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string filePath;

    [FilePath]
    public string FilePath
    {
        get { return filePath; }
        set
        {
            filePath = value;
            ValidateProperty(value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged(FilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

**FilePath.cs**

```
public sealed class FilePath : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists((string)value))
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Requires Valid File Path", 
                    new string[] { validationContext.MemberName });
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your case, but you can give a try,

[TextBox with validation loses ErrorTemplate on tab change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907075/textbox-with-validation-loses-errortemplate-on-tab-change)

btw, i'm not the downvoter :)

Comment: Will have a check, looks promising. Be good to know why it was.